# Building zlib & libz as CMake ExternalProjects

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to make a superbuild using cmake to abstract the whole dependencies hassle, zlib configures, builds and installs pretty smoothly, but libz doesn't.

External CMakeLists:

```
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(zlib
    URL https://github.com/madler/zlib/archive/refs/tags/v1.2.11.zip
    URL_HASH MD5=9d6a627693163bbbf3f26403a3a0b0b1
    DOWNLOAD_DIR ${DEPEND_DIR}/zlib/repo
    SOURCE_DIR ${DEPEND_DIR}/zlib/src
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    CMAKE_ARGS -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON
               -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${DEPEND_DIR}/zlib/install
               -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}   
    STEP_TARGETS configure build install         
)

set(ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR ${DEPEND_DIR}/zlib/install/include)
set(ZLIB_LIB_DIR ${DEPEND_DIR}/zlib/install/lib)

ExternalProject_Add(libz
    URL https://github.com/nih-at/libzip/archive/refs/tags/v1.7.3.zip
    URL_HASH MD5=98b4817aaa1f382513f08838c7192cbd
    DEPENDS zlib-install
    DOWNLOAD_DIR ${DEPEND_DIR}/libz/repo
    SOURCE_DIR ${DEPEND_DIR}/libz/src
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    CMAKE_ARGS  -D ENABLE_BZIP2=OFF
                -D ENABLE_LZMA=OFF
                -D ENABLE_GNUTLS=OFF
                -D ENABLE_MBEDTLS=OFF
                -D ENABLE_OPENSSL=OFF
                -D BUILD_REGRESS=OFF
                -D BUILD_DOC=OFF
                -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF
                -D LIBZIP_DO_INSTALL=ON
                -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON
                -D ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR}
                -D ZLIB_LIBRARY_RELEASE=${ZLIB_LIB_DIR}
                -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
                -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${DEPEND_DIR}/libz/install
)
```

Here's the error:

```
[  1%] Linking C shared library libzip.dll
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:/Workspace/Simulation/TestProject/dependencies/zlib/install/lib: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[5]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/zip.dir/build.make:1988: lib/libzip.dll] Error 1
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:174: lib/CMakeFiles/zip.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [external/CMakeFiles/libz.dir/build.make:86: external/libz-prefix/src/libz-stamp/libz-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:237: external/CMakeFiles/libz.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:111: all] Error 2
```

Bearing in mind, I don't have admin access unfortunately.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `ZLIB_LIBRARY_RELEASE` should be the path of the library file, not a folder. But anyway, instead of this fragile and legacy strategy, I advice to append install folder of zlib (`${DEPEND_DIR}/zlib/install`) to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` during libzip configuration.

Comment: Have you considered using conan?